# Function to toggle Boolean value in spreadsheet cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want this function to toggle the Boolean value in cell `D38` from `true` to `false`, or from `false` to `true`.

```js
function changeState() {
  var a=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('D38');
  a=!a;
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('D38').setValue(a);
};
```

It's not currently doing what I want: It will convert a `TRUE` to `FALSE`, but will not convert a `FALSE` to `TRUE` no matter what.

Why is it behaving like this, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Do you have anything in your JavaScript console?

Comment: You're likely going to need to post a link to a fiddle or to your code -- there's not enough information here to diagnose your problem.

a = !a should work to flip the value whether you're dealing with a string 'true' or a proper boolean.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If one of the answers below are helpful, please click the accept checkmark on the best one to the left of the answer. Otherwise, comments about the answer are appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation, [`getRange`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange%28String%29) returns an object of type [`Range`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range). The problem is that `!a` is negating the truth value of this object, not the value stored in the cell. So regardless of what the actual value is stored within that cell this will always return false (unless `a` is null).

You need to get the actual value from the cell using the appropriate [`getValue`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue%28%29) / [`setValue`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValue%28Object%29) methods:

```
function changeState() {
   var a = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('D38'); 
   var value = a.getValue();
   value = !value;
   a.setValue(value);
};
```

Or more simply:

```
function changeState() {
   var a = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('D38'); 
   a.setValue(!a.getValue());
};
```